# Converting Curl Request Into C# ASP.NET Web Request Stripe Payments API

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, curl, stripe-payments

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges 
\ -u sk_test_BQokikJOvB432343iI2HlWgH4olfQ2: 
\ -d amount=400 
\ -d currency=usd 
\ -d card=tok_15CVG02eZvKYlo2CDVUHUs56
```

I'm new to curl and need to convert the above curl request into an ASP.NET web request. I believe the -d are post parameters, but I am unsure how to pass in the -u and what -u stands for. Below is the code I have so far. FYI this is for the Stripe Payment Gateway, I can't use the ASP.NET Library because I can add any dlls to the solution I am running so I am using their CURL API.

```
string formencodeddata = "amount=400&currency=usd&card=tok_15CVG02eZvKYlo2CDVUHUs56";
byte[] formbytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(formencodeddata);

//Create a new HTTP request object, set the method to POST and write the POST data to it
var webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges");
webrequest.Method = "POST";
webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

using (Stream postStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream()) {
    postStream.Write(formbytes, 0, formbytes.Length);
}

//Make the request, get a response and pull the data out of the response stream
var webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = webresponse.GetResponseStream();
var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: probaply you can check a [.net]https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net version of stripe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my final solution:

```
var postUrl = new StringBuilder();

postUrl.Append("card=");
postUrl.Append(token);
postUrl.Append("currency=usd");
postUrl.Append("&x_amount=");
postUrl.Append(transactionAmount.ToString());

byte[] formbytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(postUrl.ToString());

//Create a new HTTP request object, set the method to POST and write the POST data to it
var webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
webrequest.Method = "POST";
webrequest.UserAgent = "Stripe Payment Processor";
webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webrequest.Headers.Add("Stripe-Version", "2014-12-22");
webrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Concat("Basic ", (Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:", this.PrivateKey))))));

using (Stream postStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    postStream.Write(formbytes, 0, formbytes.Length);
}

//Make the request, get a response and pull the data out of the response stream

StreamReader reader = null;
string stripeResponse; 
try
{
    HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
    Stream responseStream = webresponse.GetResponseStream();
    reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    stripeResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
catch (WebException exception)
{
    using (WebResponse response = exception.Response)
    {
        using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (reader = new StreamReader(data))
        {
            stripeResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```